# Can I call an interactive script in orther bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

For example,there is an interactive script that read user input his name.And then write the name in a file.

```
#! /bin/bash 
read name
echo $name>>name.txt
```

If I can't change the interactive script , how can I use anothor bash to quote the interactive script?

**For example,I want to write a bash that extracts the name from a text and then calls this interactive script.**

So can I achieve my idea?

Comment: That should be `#!/bin/bash` (no space character)

Comment: @knittl The space is optional... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was under the impression that this could cause problems. This question and answer have more details: <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang>. Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [pipe](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/introduction-pipes-linux) to combine output of one program with the input of the next program:

```
echo 'name from other script' | ./script1.sh
```

`echo` can be replaced with any other executable file or script:

```sh
$ cat >script2.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'first input'
echo 'second input'
^D
$ chmod u+x script2.sh
$ ./script2.sh | ./script1.sh
```

---

If your intended input name is already in a file, use *IO redirection* instead:

```sh
$ ./script2.sh < file_containing_name.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. But if this bash has two input variables.

Comment: ```#! /bin/bash
read -p 'name:' name
echo "name is $name"
read -p 'date:' date
echo "date is $date" ```

Comment: I describe more detailed questions in the answer below, hope you can help me.Thank you very much.

Comment: `( echo'line 1 of input'; echo 'line 2 of input; echo 'line 3 of input'; ) | ./script1.sh` the commands inside the subshell invocation can be put into a script (`script2.sh`)